# Output ISO8601 date string from seconds and nanoseconds

Tags: code-golf, date

One reason why [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the best date string format, is that you can simply append as much precision as you like. Given 2 integers representing seconds and nanoseconds that have passed since `1970-01-01T00:00:00`, return an ISO8601 string as described below.

**Output:**

The standard output format without timezone looks like this:

`1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001`

The date is encoded as "year, month,day" with 4,2,2 digits respectively, separated by a "-". The time of day is encoded as "hour, minute, seconds" with 2,2,2 digits respectively. Then, optionally a dot with exactly 6 digits of precision can follow, encoding microseconds that have passed after the given date+(time in hours+minutes+seconds) since. This is only appended if it'd be not equal to 000000. See examples below

Yes, we are allowed to append 6 digits(microseconds) of precision and theoretically more are simply appendable,  though not defined further in the standard.

**Input:**

You'll get 2 integers(seconds, nanoseconds). For the sake of simplicity, let's constrain them to be within `0 <= x < 10^9` both. Make sure to discard/round down any precision beyond microseconds.

**Examples:**

```
Input: 616166982 , 34699909     Output: 1989-07-11T13:29:42.034699
Input: 982773555 , 886139278    Output: 2001-02-21T16:39:15.886139
Input: 885454423 , 561869693    Output: 1998-01-22T07:33:43.561869
Input: 0         , 100000       Output: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000100
Input: 0         , 1000         Output: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001
Input: 0         , 999          Output: 1970-01-01T00:00:00
Input: 999999999 , 999999999    Output: 2001-09-09T01:46:39.999999
```

**Task:**

Provide a function that takes in 2 integers as described in the Input section and returns a String as described in the Output section.

For details and limitations for input/output please refer to the [default input/output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

This is codegolf: Shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: I'd recommend some more test cases just for clarity, and you should probably specify what ISO8601 is; challenges should be complete on their own for the most part.

Comment: added! Did I miss anything?

Comment: Looks pretty good for now.

Comment: I think you should add an input example where the nanos is 0, since that's potentially a special case (I know it was for me).

Comment: Can we include leading `0`s in the second input?

Comment: The question does not state whether this is counting leap seconds.

Comment: @Shaggy what do you mean by leading 0s? In which part of the output?

Comment: @JdeBP Ooof I hadn't considered that beforehand TBH. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50910322/6301103) unix timestamps don't produce skipped leap seconds but the skipped second *is* a valid ISO8601 date.

As far as I understand it, you may ingore leap seconds as they may be represented in a valid timestamp according to the standard.

Comment: @jaaq, can we pad the nanoseconds _input_ with leading `0`s so its length is always 9 digits?

Comment: The way the standard is now, only microseconds(6 digits) are mentioned in the standard. The microsecond digits are either 6 digits or 0 digits. See TC 4,5 and 6.

Comment: No, what I'm asking is if we can take the second **_input_** with leading `0`s, e.g. `034699909` instead of `34699909`.

Comment: Oh, well, you may take the input as an integer, not necessarily a built-in integer, afaik the default IO rules don't specify whether you may pad your input/take an integer as a string with padded 0s. Open to suggestions here. What's common practice on leading 0s in integer inputs?

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + sed, <s>37</s>, <s>59</s>, 50 bytes

```bash
printf '%(%FT%T)T.%06d' $1 $[$2/1000]
```

```bash
printf "%(%FT%T)T.%06d" $1 ${2::-3}|sed s/\\.0*$//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy9DoJAEIT7e4oNgURNhPtdbrH3CeiAAuUMJAQMkFiIz45nos4U800xc6nndnu0Xe9gcnUDPaxrUUDYQ1WdmhFmt/iy3aduWG4QRLvonEf5Po8jjk0AoYDwKbPsqF7r7BqYk7KM@SFMks1d29E/DG5D4Y1kJSiNRMSJ@ZKmyhgD1qJQJFPLrDXaaC0VGBQWCUkxDoJ/9AUffs/oJ/jTGw)

8 bytes saved thanks to @DigitalTrauma

Comment: You're failing the \$6^{th}\$ testcase. Microseconds are only supposed to be appended if not equal to \$0\$.

Comment: @Noodle9, fixed

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, yes `${2::-3}` saves 2, the space is not needed after the second `:`

Comment: Does this work regardless of the system's time zone?

Comment: @M.Justin right, fortunately on [tio timezone is utc](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUFJVUPVLUQ1RDNET9XALEVJwdDI2MTUjCs1OSOfKyWxJFVBt9SzODVZQTfFAUlKQSUk6v9/AA), otherwise should be `TZ=UTC printf ...`

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p` `-MPOSIX+strftime` `-Minteger`), <s>55</s>, <s>51</s>, 60 bytes

Thanks to @Abigail for giving me the idea to change the input format. + 9 bytes to handle the microseconds=0 case.

```perl
$_=(strftime"%FT%T",gmtime$_).sprintf".%06d",<>/1e3
```

```perl
$_=(strftime"%FT%T",gmtime$_).sprintf".%06d",<>/1e3;s;\.0+$;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5LC8IwEITv@RmhBcW2Js2jWaoeBQ@iYA8ehF5MS6GPkOb3G1NUnGXZbxYGxmjbC@@jer@anW1cN2gcH6u4wkk7LC6q19lsbDe6BmcxkU@c7A5bqlk5l4@MbKLSe0nDSFA5YlwCAAEUTFEwIQRSSlIGeaECCS44zxkSkioJEhgiiJJFXwgn5Jf96E@vybhuGmef9san5@vldrpvfpXDIxTUrbZv)

Comment: If you add `-F/,/` as an option, replace ``$` ``by `$_`, and `$'` by `$F[1]`, you can [save a byte](https://tio.run/##PU47C8IwGNzzM0ILimmbNI/mG1wLDqKggyDSxbQU@ghpfr8xBevdcA84OGvcIENImuNu8a71/WhwWt/TOybduKak2eeLdf3kW5ynVL0xSeonexXM8BAUi1SgS8KFAgAKKIaq4lJKorViHMpKI62lkEKUnEjFtAIFHFHC6IqfiRL3CDaQv/vM1vfztIRssCE7Xy@30@OwnY1FvGY640JWF6T4Ag).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 91 bytes

```
DateString[6!3068040+#2,"ISODateTime"]<>If[#>999,"."<>IntegerString[⌊#/1000⌋,10,6],""]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xjsIwDIb3vsUlEssZzmkSN5GOioGF6U4qW9UhQil0aAeUrSoPwPGUvEhJxIG9fP5/@bd7F06@d6E7uLldz1sXfBXO3XCs6UMiGVT4yXNgu@onefuu96z5LndtzUtrLbAVi9MQ/NGf/xfvtyv/Eoh4v/2BQKAGGGsW8290Q82XZbvZ8GZxqQ5uuIzZKBXFJLRAIjZZk0@QjcaQkDYvDEShKKTWOsmahCFLVoIxWmmlcpnkdA4R8MVPSg@@4Fnwpimb5gc)

Mathematica supports milliseconds, but not microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>108</s> 106 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
#import<time.h>
o[9];f(s,n)long s;{strftime(o,99,"%FT%T",gmtime(&s));printf((n/=1e3)?"%s.%06d":"%s",o,n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLbbqMwEH3PV1hesYLWUF/AYOjlodr9At6aaFWBSZE2JsI8RBvl27MDhrRR1RoD9pyZ4zOeqcJtVZ3PP9rdvuuH@6Hd6ejtcdW9qE3R@JaY4G9ntsgWRzv0zQj7HVGKYO936ZWYbHeT7acNgmLft2ZofN/cPTAtgifs2cijssY5rDDpgKw4ncEH7V5b4wer4wrBGA2DtsMf@7JBD@goGTxSZZwg@KSpSJKEoCxL4iSOuSCILlMt41RcMxnHJGIJIFVjtGRC8TQjKJEsk0oqIGJ0HO4/sX2mrN5e@xukD3tdDbp2tJipTIU0DRkrmci5ymMe0ekwTBDmlLKQ8pADKnOhcpZE7vwRZUplIThwXtI0FyKPReQkOTSlI0pZSWk@zQjEgcBvUMC/QN/lgF5VUpbHo6LIpYivcuzn5NaHX3x9UM/wJmP8h71YIpqu98fLbk2tDxBFi3l5j2z7T3eNv9xYcDcbbi6WAt3eTt4Bcg2wlM4C09wIE74prmCzwOYTPHce9mri1Sh8RCDcEgT9dnFxzfy@nwsLnJfifsWKfM8GawOceiY4rU7n/w)

Inputs seconds and nanoseconds as integers and outputs the formatted date/time to `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>32</s> 28 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a pair of strings, with the nanoseconds first. Can save (at least) 4 bytes if we can include leading `0`s with the nanoseconds.

```
ùT9 ¯6
pU=n g)iÐV*A³ s3 ¯UÄ9
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=%2bVQ5IK82CnBVPW4gZylp0FYqQbMgczMgr1XEOQ&input=IjM0Njk5OTA5IgoiNjE2MTY2OTgyIg)

Or, to "translate" that to JavaScript:

```
U=>V=>(
    U=U.padStart(9,0).slice(0,6),
    U.repeat(U=Math.sign(parseInt(U))).replace(/^/,new Date(V*10**3).toISOString().slice(0,U+19))
)
```

```
ùT9 ¯6\npU=n g)iÐV*A³ s3 ¯UÄ9     :Implicit input of strings U=nanoseconds & V=seconds
ù                                 :Left pad U
 T                                :  With 0
  9                               :  To length 9
    ¯6                            :Slice to length 6
      \n                          :Reassign to U
        p                         :Repeat U
         U=                       :  Reassign to U
           n                      :  Convert to integer
             g                    :  Get sign
              )                   :End repeat
               i                  :Prepend
                Ð                 :  Create Date object from
                 V*               :    V multiplied by
                   A              :    10
                    ³             :    Cubed
                      s3          :  To ISO String
                         ¯U       :  Slice to length U
                           Ä9     :    +19
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>62 60</s> 68 bytes

```
f={s,n->"${java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(s,n|1)}"[0..25]-~/\.0+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndFNS8NAEAbgu79iKYW22N3O7Fd2FurNg2dzUw@htn6AiTShILX@9ThNXBWlFnyTwzCbZ5Od3K2ravPStqv5tp6W8mww3D4Wm0I1D09LdVHWTVE2qlqdP1eL@8vloipvx/zcK052gytQSrsb@Ta7VnA6nO3aoq6X60aMkAJJyCRijiZqilYrMNYTjcR8LlZjj3x5ClpMRdcnoMlJ4hoAJWipmftoKKJTIXg0iTPMMuOcY94v6Cx8eSQKkrfQOocsGhOtUc5j8MmH4KyzVhv2/YIn891nsPeAOUDsbgX8TQAfHkTKVHCXw@VRzzsc8F35px8l8Mvz7MQP38@P/wDlgNHuR6ioS5pfSu/7/PP9n/Wx8@8PenB@3Jm07w)

### Explanation

The Java `ofEpochSecond(epochSecond, nanoAdjustment)` method returns the `Instant` corresponding to the given seconds and nanoseconds (exactly what we want for this challenge).  The nanoseconds are bitwise-ORed with `1` to ensure we never end up with exactly 0 or 1_000_000 nanoseconds, while still maintaining the same 6-digit rounding behavior.

`"${...}"` converts the `Instant` to a [`GString`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) consisting of the `String` value of the instant.  The `toString` representation of an `Instant` is in ISO-8601 format: "2011-12-03T10:15:30.000000001Z".  It automatically excludes extra decimal places past 0/3/6 decimal places (seconds/milliseconds/microseconds) if the remaining digits are 0, hence the earlier bitwise-OR.

`"${value}"[0..25]` returns characters 0 through 25 of the string, which is up through the sixth decimal place.

`-~/\.0+$/` subtracts the first instance of the regex pattern `\.0+$` from the resulting string; namely, a decimal place followed by all zeros, followed by the end of the string.  This will only match if the string ends in `.000000`, and the code is one character shorter than subtracting `'.000000'`.

Comment: This looks quite neat. Care to explain a bit, though?

Comment: @Adám Added explanation (and found a bug)

Comment: Thanks. So your answer is currently invalid. Maybe delete it, then edit it, and then undelete when ready? This could save you from downvotes.

Comment: @Adám Fixed the bug with a bitwise OR hack. Reduced by a byte by subtracting a regex rather than a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```
f={s,n->sprintf('%tFT%1$tT.%06d',s*1000L,n/1E3as int)-~/\.0+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndE9T8MwEAbgnV/hoVFaiN07f8VnqWwwMXpkqQRBLClqIiSE4K@HS4IBgUqlXjJY5zy27s3Dfrd7fhmGZvPaVa287J72j23fLMuiv04FLvqkCvB3ZdWdIwDcVO0ar8y2E/zVSr6vbxVcLNZvw7br7ve9KJECSaglYkITNUWrFRjriUqx2Yhm6ZEfT0GLSkx9AlqdZa4BUIKWmrmPhiI6FYJHkznDujbOOebzhq7Dt0eiIPkIrRPU0ZhojXIeg88@BGedtdqwnzc8mZ@@htEDJoA4vYrH5tE/PYhclRgDgbFx1PMJB/y0/NeXGfzxnJ345ef8@A9QAox2jFDRVDm/XLOf68T7v9bH5h8HPZgfd1bDBw)

A different Groovy approach using format strings (inspired by other similar answers).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/) <strike>106</strike>, 81 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:datetime.fromtimestamp(a+b//1e3/1e6).isoformat()
from datetime import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBNasMwEEb3OsWgleSqjk2g1AYdIKtcIFBGWE4E0Q/KZJHTO1JMoNBFFukIMbN48xi@dKNTDNvvlJdZH5YzejMhoDLjhGTJedvOOfo6XAh9EvhhNpvebsv/kq27xDlmjyQkqxw8t8D5FDM1y9ohY5iiZ6iN7rumGeCzZym7QILvQrrSyBUqXp5RNkyaH4jLJ7C/0krMAhUYKYumY1VU6180b0uGYXjDUTKEH3ChxnS0ou/kyKAUgoa6sqbXrk3I5hGhfCDmNfLyrl/Qn9uWOw)

Comment: I'll make a start with an example, though there probably still is some room for improvements.

Comment: 81 bytes (the `f=` doesn't count): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBNasMwEEb3PsWgleQojk0g1C46QFa5QKCMsNwKoh/kySKnd6SYQKGLLNIZhAb09Bi@eKOf4PcfMS3LlIKDEcmQdQasiyFR/TmpCzo9IqDUw/O1KWwZZkIXOW70bteZfT4H0dg5TCE5JC6W1QIJ/RhchUqrrq3rHrZdFZP1xNnRxysNTKJkubU0flTsTEw8gdOVVmLiKEELkTVtVUSl/kXztqTv@zccOS34AutLTN@Gd60YKsiFoKB8WdNr1ouL@hGheCD6NfJyr1/Qn92WOw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice! If that's the case I'll add it to the header :)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>83  94 ...</s>  78 bytes

```javascript
s=>n=>new Date(s*1e3).toJSON(n=0|n/1e3).slice(0,20-!n)+`${n+1e6}`.slice(n?1:7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNS8QwEIbv/RVj8NDaD2eSNk0C1YsnD3pwb2vBRbqwIllpiy6s@9vXabqCwk4@mfd5J0zeVp@r4bXffIz5pzmum@PQ3Hie3RfcrcYuHq6oU0kxbu@fHh9i3@C3vw6Z4X3z2sWYScwvfJK@XO59Sp0@vJwUf0uuTo5jN4xDs1xq4qGtkZCBKrW1Fi1kgqyxOdY50YKUk9aVssCgizZbMl7XqqoqNhmjSVlZG74LiUg5ylyyTTtlHVXFDEw2Y6qyKkupGK00GW21VeExa3I2SrnA2inlSlXM@uQCZJxwCgjB75CtcXIgLRBdmAXrTP1zhNpnSWZnMgNu@TwXAPsbkP29nzrlP7ILJFdOzRazKNo2itbbPn7vRtjtdrBdQ/jtZB/BlOsbWMcsLLFNwkltEsFHv/HjKZ2KTKSzkgpwz15ACj0vAc@etzTmIs0EyDZJBetJdIiOPw)

- Thanks to @Neil for the great help!
- Saved another 5 thanks to @Arnauld

Comment: You don't need the `()`s around `new Date(s*1e3)`, and you can save another 2 bytes using `(n/1e6).toFixed(6).slice(2)`.

Comment: Also, you're not supposed to have the `.000000` when `n=0` for some reason.

Comment: Oh, speaking of misreading the question, I hadn't noticed that you need to truncate the nanoseconds. Never mind.

Comment: @Neil thanks , I missed that, so I just have to fix the 0 microseconds case and leave the () ?

Comment: You can save a byte by moving the `n=0|n/1e3` into the `toISOString` parameter, leaving just `!n`, and another byte by using `n?2:8` instead of `6*!n+2` (also note that you only need to add `1e6` and slice by `n?1:7`).

Comment: You can use `toJSON()` instead of `toISOString()`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) 18.0, 53 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program. Prompts for nanoseconds, then seconds.

```apl
(¯7×0=f)↓⊃'%ISO%.ffffff'(1200⌶)20 1⎕DT⎕+1E¯6×f←⌊⎕÷1E3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVA9SwNBEO3vV2wT9o58sLt3u7cbEASTIpUB01gG4olwmGBsgrFRuRxnLigSzsbKxi6FaMAy90/mj8RJgtE0vt1i581b3ptp98JyZ9AOu6dLiKNaC6KHKyGl0kVIP/K5Vh5j14RA@kJ63XAQnIUhCboXhOsKo30Ck2mtZTVWvyC5sWm53KpW6b4tim6eQfouHYgTSKeLNxuS2xJnrMghfoboyVEQPXbalyfo45QEMgp1fLh2zDM@RJ5A8kroSkTR6OCYdoLzPiVwf4eBvvD@l2z8aUE8ai7txczPM7YXOOiBIWihcXRYqARrUJsLxhqOYIRv5p9Mi7y@mKk8C3AqGCfI5HNed3E/oyVZo2m5njLGMGMpjkcZLayfltaKu0b42kLW910p5bYnFdfKKOOiSnrS84S77eFuEBbbIf6U6LdbbfD7@gY) (polyfills for `⌶` and `⎕DT` because TIO still uses 17.1)

`⎕÷1E3` divide input nanoseconds by 1000

`f←` assign to `f`

`1E¯6×` multiply by 0.000001

`⎕+` add input seconds to that

`20 1⎕DT` convert from UNIX time (seconds since 1970) to Dyalog Date Number (days since 1989-12-31)

`'%ISO%.ffffff'(1200⌶)` format according to ISO with six-digit fractional second precision

`⊃` disclose (because a "string" is an enclosed character vector)

`(`…`)↓` drop the following number of characters

`0=f` one if `f` is zero

`¯7×` seven from the rear if so (lit. negative seven multiplied by that)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>102</s> 101 bytes

```
=TEXT(25569+A1/86400,"yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXT(B1/10^9,"."&REPT(0,9)),7),".000000",)
```

Input is seconds in `A1` and nanoseconds in `B1`.

There are two major pieces to this:

---

`TEXT(25569+A1/86400,"yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")`
`25569` is the numerical equivalent of 1970-01-01 in Excel which measures from 1900-01-00 as zero.
`A1/86400` converts seconds into days.
`"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"` formats the result, giving us the majority of the desired output.

---

`SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXT(B1/10^9,"."&REPT(0,9)),7),".000000",)`
`TEXT(B1/10^9,"."&REPT(0,9))` converts from an integer of nanoseconds to a decimal of seconds.
`LEFT(TEXT(~),7)` gives the decimal point with the leading 6 digits.
`SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(~),".000000",)` accounts for a <1,000 nanoseconds by dropping the result.

---

Aside: Given how friendly Excel is with dates, it makes sense - but is still annoying - that it takes more bytes to deal with `.000000` than it does to deal with `1970-01-01T00:00:00`. I found alternate approaches with less bytes but they only work if we can round the nanoseconds or display zero values. Alack and alas.

Comment: Given the date constraint of between 0 & 10^9, you can save a byte by changing the year format to "yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <strike>46 bytes</strike> 40 chars, 42 bytes

```perl6
{(~DateTime.new($^a+$^b divⅯ/1e6)).chop}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBNSgNBEAXg/ZyiwCAJZtqq/q9u3HmEWQdGnWDAaFBRgujO83gnLzLWpGdwk7zuTdH10fB23fOD77d7OF/DVf8x/7puX7tms@3UY/c@n63ai9nqBu42b7/fP5fU@cVC3d4/7T77XFUv7R7W4EmO56hhCcZ6ZkbOAGdAHLnGUBM1ZJLmZLXCw8YoxYRgnHMiY/RkWIeYRWpEqlHXWqRPhhM5VRZGGaOzzlptRDpP0bNnkw9/cqwFa91gSMYka1RZGCXClCUQDsnDMMiAg0RqENPhKnmVnRMyl@GkFHtESj0jPC6naqYUUvJfjfTKDVKyQzuqvFb9Hw)

Saved a few bytes by using a non-digit numeral (which could be replaced by others like `൲`, but others like  or  add an extra byte), which allowed the space removed after `div`.  Only trick here was needing to force the round down, and stringify the `DateTime` to be able to `.chop`.  There may in fact be a bug here in that Rakudo's implementation rounds up, and if we consider it as such, then it can be further golfed to

```perl6
{(~DateTime.new($^a+$^b/1e9)).chop}
```

Which would only be 35 chars/bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 42 bytes

Uses `-rtime` flag to get `Time#iso8601`.

```ruby
~(~(:at&Time)&:nsec)|~:iso8601&6|~:[]&26&0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXJVtJJuUUlmbqpS7CI326WlJWm6Fje16jTqNKwSS9RCgBKaalZ5xanJmjV1VpnF-RZmBoZqZkB2dKyakZmaAUTH7oLSkmIFt2gzQyA0s7Qw0lEwNjGztLQ0sIyFqFiwAEIDAA)

### Explanation

```ruby
~(~(:at & Time) & :nsec) |  # Time.at(secs, nsecs, :nsec), then
~:iso8601 & 6 |             # ISO-8601 w/ 6 fractional digits, then
~:[] & 26 & 0               # Get first 26 chars (drop time zone)
```